# Setting UIViewRepresentable height

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have some UITextView which I want to place inside a VStack. I want them to display one directly under the other and completely expanded, without having to scroll inside the TextView.

```
struct TextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let text : String
    let titulo : String
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let textView = UITextView()
        
        textView.isEditable = false
        textView.isSelectable = false
        textView.bounces = false
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {//Needs to execute in another thread, otherwise it crashes (Swift bug)
            textView.attributedText = text.htmlToAttributedString(size: 16, titulo: titulo)
        }
        
        return textView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

My view looks like:

```
struct PageView: View {

    let sampleText = """
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</h1>
<h2>consectetur adipiscing elit,</h2>
<h3> sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<h3>
<p> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p><br>
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.<br>
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
"""
    
    var body: some View{
        TabView{
            HStack{
                VStack{
                    //Views that take up half of the screen
                }
                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                    ScrollView{
                        TextView(text: sampleText, titulo: "")
                        TextView(text: sampleText, titulo: "")
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }
        }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
    }
}
```

And my htmlToAttributedString function:

```
    func htmlToAttributedString(size: CGFloat, titulo: String) -> NSAttributedString? {
        
        var attributedString = NSAttributedString()
        
        let texto = self.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "<br>")

        
        if(!self.isEmpty)
        {
            var htmlTemplate = """
            <!doctype html>
            <html>
              <head>
                <style>
                  body {
                    font-family: -apple-system;
                    font-size: \(size)px;
                  }
                </style>
              </head>
              <body>
            """
            
            if(titulo != "")
            {
                htmlTemplate += "<h3>\(titulo)</h3>"
            }
            
            htmlTemplate += """
                \(texto)
              </body>
            </html>
            """

                guard let data = htmlTemplate.data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString(string: "No se han obtenido los datos correctamente")}
                    do {

                        attributedString = try NSAttributedString(
                              data: data,
                              options: [
                                .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                                .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue,
                                
                              ],
                              documentAttributes: nil)
                        
                    } catch {}
                  }
            
            return attributedString
        }
}
```

I've already tried scaledToFit, maxHeight = .infinity and fixedSize.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is there empty space where the text views should be showing text? To answer the title of the question, `UITextView` has an initializer that lets you set the text view's frame, which would set the text view's height.

Comment: With the posted code, no text is displayed. I can't use frame because I can't get the height properly (DispatchQueue.main.aysnc). Using scaledToFit or scaledToFill there is some empty space between the views.

Comment: And frame in UITextView's initializer doesn't work neither, It doesn't display anything

Answer (score 1):

Well, the view doesn't display just because the `ScrollView`, eliminate the `ScrollView` to the following code:

```swift
    var body: some View{
        TabView{
            HStack{
                VStack{
                    //Views that take up half of the screen
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                }
                TextView(text: sampleText, titulo: "")
                TextView(text: sampleText, titulo: "")
            }
        }
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
```

Maybe this will be the result that you want.

Comment: It's not exactly what I want (I would like the TextViews being fully displayed, without having to scroll inside them) but it's an advance. Thanks! Why does the ScrollView makes the text not displaying?

Comment: If you want to show the text inside `ScrollView`, you may need to set the `.frame()` to `TextView()`. But I am a little confused what if the text is so large that can't be put just inside a view, in this case, what is the meaning of "without having to scroll inside them"?

Comment: I use the TextView because the text is a HTML, so I need it to be an attributedString. Do you refer to a View or an UIView?

Comment: So I thought about what you commented and I used UILabel instead and made it work with constraints. Thank you.

Comment: Well, for the first peek of this question, I was a little confused that why you want to use UITextView not `UILabe`l in UIKit or `Text` in SwiftUI, now I still have no idea....

Comment: Basically at the beginning of the project I needed the scroll inside de text, that's why I used UITextView. Later, due to some changes, I didn't need it anymore. And about SwiftUI's Text, I need it to be an HTML, and SwiftUI doesn't have an alternative to AttributedString yet.